# How to leave erlang shell without shutting down erlang VM

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I searched for this and found that the command is `Ctrl-D`, but that is not working for me.

Rest all options are shutting the VM down.

I am using `erlang 19.3` with erlang.mk

`Ctrl-D` is working supposedly for rest of the logins and shell. This is so strange. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Ctrl-D` doesn't do anything for me either (Terminal App/OSX 10.10.5/Erlang 19.2).

Comment: @7stud If you are using erlang.mk checkout the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems `Ctrl-D` only works for attach console.

`make run` with `erlang.mk` opens up the main console, quitting which always shutdowns the erlang VM.

I went and ran `./XXX_release start` as generated by erlang.mk build.
This starts the VM without running the console.

Then `./XXX_release attach` which attaches to the VM of the previous step. `Ctrl-D` works on this as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can quit with the command:

```erlang
q().
```

This might not work because of the previous commands. If that is the case then forget the previous commands by first running the command below f() the q() above:

```erlang
f().
```

This takes you out of the erlang shell.

After leaving the shell you can view running processes. View running processes in linux/mac by running the command below on your terminal, if you are using windows then use windows task manager to see if erlang is running:

```sh
ps -ax
```